# Generic Generator parameters in Hibernate cannot be set

Tags: hibernate, annotations, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I want to use foreign strategy generator for one of key properties in my class. The easiest way as shown in:
http://blog.eyallupu.com/2011/01/hibernatejpa-identity-generators.html
or
http://www.coderanch.com/t/219256/ORM/databases/HBM-Annotation-Foreign-Generator
or
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/

```java
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
...
...
...
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "myForeignGenerator",
        strategy = "foreign",
        parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "osoba"))
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "myForeignGenerator")
@Column(name = "IdPracownik", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getIdPracownik() {
    return this.idPracownik;
}
```

and Eclipse shows error:

*"Type mismatch: cannot convert from Parameter to Annotation"*, underlining "@Parameter" annotation.

Why is that?

Comment: Show your import statements

Comment: updated question with import statements

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're using [`javax.persistence.Parameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Parameter.html) instead of using [`org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Parameter.html).

Importing all classes from a package is generally considered as a bad practice. Only import the classes that you need.

Comment: Ah, I knew some day I was going to regret importing *...
It works just fine with org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter.
Thanks!